# sqlite3 Setting an "ON CONFLICT" clause to "DELETE FROM table"

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite there is an `ON CONFLICT` clause for inserts and updates, which allows you to do something if an insert or update causes a key violation: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

I want to know if its possible anyway (maybe with triggers) to emulate an `UPDATE ON CONFLICT DELETE` clause, which is the opposite (kind of) of `UPDATE ON CONFLICT REPLACE`. Basically, if updating row `X` creates a conflict with pre-existing row `Y`, I want to delete row `X` (because its non-updated form is an error). The `REPLACE` keyword seems to delete all the `Y`s and then adds in `X`. I need other columns (that are not in conflict) of the `Y` row to remain, not the new `X` row, so I cannot use `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in ON CONFLICT clause that implements this algorithm.

You have to implement the duplicate check and the deletion/update in your code.